# Can the src attribute of an iframe perform a POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, post, iframe

I need to load an iframe using a src attribute. There is a lot of additional information I need to attach to the query. Currently, I just put all this information in a parameter like so:

```
<iframe src="mywebsite.com/get_iframe?aVeryLongString"></iframe>
```

However, aVeryLongString can get very long. So long that I get a "414 (Request-URI Too Large)" error from the server.

Is there a way to make this request without getting this error?

Note: The url of the iframe comes with its own Content-Security-Policy, so I can't just use srcdoc instead of src. Unless there is a way to force the CSP even if you use srcdoc?

Comment: What's the form of `aVeryLongString`? `name1=value1&name2=value2` or something else?

Comment: Why not just make an AJAX Post Request and populate a `div`?

Comment: I forgot to mention in the example, but the iframe is sandboxed and its content is very insecure. That's why it needs a CSP of its own, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `iframe` will contain HTML, I would lean toward doing what [Scott marcus mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027873/can-the-src-attribute-of-an-iframe-perform-a-post-request/52027985?noredirect=1#comment91006200_52027873): Doing an ajax POST and populating a `div` rather than using an `iframe`.

But if you can't do that for whatever reason (and there could be several reasons you couldn't, not least if the `iframe` will have content other than HTML):

If `aVeryLongString` is in the standard URI-encoded `name1=value1&name2=value2` form, you can give the `iframe` a `name`, and then POST a form to it from JavaScript code. Very roughly:

```
<iframe name="the-iframe"></iframe>
<script>
(function() { // Scoping IIFE to avoid creating global vars
    var form, input;
    form = document.createElement("form");
    form.action = "/path/to/the/resource"; // I didn't use your `src` because it's incorrect
    form.target = "the-iframe";
    for (/*...looping through the fields you need to add...*/) {
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "hidden";
        input.name = /*...the field name...*/;
        input.value = /*...the field value...*/;
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
})();
</script>
```

---

Side note: `src="mywebsite.com/get_iframe"` is incorrect, the URL would be `//mywebsite.com/get_iframe` (a protocol-relative URL) or, if the page is being loaded from that site, `/get_iframe` or possibly `./get_iframe`.

Comment: It's almost working, but instead of populating the iframe with the content, the content is opened in another tab for some reason.
The iframe looks like this: $(`<iframe id="${idForIframe}" name="${idForIframe}" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-popups" frameborder=0 scrolling="no"></iframe>`)

The form uses "form.target = idForIframe;"

Is there anything else?

Comment: @FlorianDietz - Is something processing those tokens? And is it client-side or server-side? It would appear the names don't match.

Comment: NVM, the problem was that the iframe was not part of the DOM yet at the time of the request, so its name was not found.

Comment: @FlorianDietz - Ah! That's why I included the actual markup above, so the `iframe` element was above the `script`. I should have said. :-)